Applying clang-tidy's readability-identifier-naming fix corrects only the header files
I'm trying to use clang-tidy with readability-identifier-naming fix to change the naming style in a small project, i.e. I want to rename multiple symbols across multiple files. For some reason clang-tidy only ever corrects the .hpp files for me, but the respective .cpp files remain unchanged.
This is a C++20 CMake-based MSVC project on Windows using the Ninja generator. I'm using CMake 3.31.0-rc1 and LLVM 18.1.8.
I run it like this for a simple SampleFile.hpp/SampleFile.cpp pair:
clang-tidy -checks="-*,readability-identifier-naming" --fix-errors -p dir\with\compile_commands .\src\SampleFile.*

For the cpp the output is:

.\src\SampleFile.cpp 10 warnings generated. Suppressed 10 warnings
(10 in non-user code).

For the hpp I get the expected output of the changes made with the final info:

clang-tidy applied 10 of 10 suggested fixes. Suppressed 11 warnings
(11 in non-user code).

After this, the hpp is refactored as expected, but the cpp remains unchanged.
To even get to this stage, I had to clean the compile_commands.json that I obtain via CMake's set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON) - for some reason CMake was populating this file with references to non-existent .modmap files, which was causing clang-tidy to fail with errors. The code is not using any modules, so I'm not sure why those were there. Regardless, even after cleaning the compile_commands.json of problematic entries, only the header file is getting fixed.
.clang-tidy contents:
---
Checks: >
  -*,
  -readability-identifier-naming

CheckOptions:
  - { key: readability-identifier-naming.NamespaceCase,            value: lower_case }
  - { key: readability-identifier-naming.ClassCase,                value: CamelCase  }
  - { key: readability-identifier-naming.StructCase,               value: CamelCase  }
  - { key: readability-identifier-naming.TemplateParameterCase,    value: CamelCase  }
  - { key: readability-identifier-naming.FunctionCase,             value: lower_case }
  - { key: readability-identifier-naming.VariableCase,             value: lower_case }
  - { key: readability-identifier-naming.MemberCase,               value: lower_case }
  - { key: readability-identifier-naming.MethodCase,               value: camelBack  }
  - { key: readability-identifier-naming.PrivateMemberPrefix,      value: 'm_'        }
  - { key: readability-identifier-naming.ProtectedMemberPrefix,    value: 'm_'        }
  - { key: readability-identifier-naming.MacroDefinitionCase,      value: UPPER_CASE }
  - { key: readability-identifier-naming.EnumConstantCase,         value: CamelCase  }
  - { key: readability-identifier-naming.ConstexprVariableCase,    value: CamelCase  }
  - { key: readability-identifier-naming.GlobalConstantCase,       value: UPPER_CASE }
  - { key: readability-identifier-naming.MemberConstantCase,       value: CamelCase  }
  - { key: readability-identifier-naming.StaticConstantCase,       value: CamelCase  }

Any ideas what I may be missing?

"for some reason CMake was populating this file with references to non-existent .modmap files" - Do those .modmap file not exist after configuration only, or they do not exist even after the building the project? Here the CMake developer tells that .modmap files are created during the build only.

@Tsyvarev modmap files are never created, not even during a full build. Not sure why.

So it looks like the core problem is that .modmap files shouldn't ever by referenced in compile_commands.json, because the project doesn't use C++ modules at all. Like described in that comment: https://discourse.cmake.org/t/how-to-control-the-location-of-the-c-20-binary-module-interface-bmi-output-directory/7968/20. You may want to submit a bugreport to CMake about that problem.
